# zen cart SQL - Select products and order by price

Tags: php, sql, database, zen-cart

**SOLVED**

See my answer below.

**BACKGROUND**

Anyone familiar with zen cart will know that it comes complete with the worlds most pointless product sort option aka the alpha drop down sorter.

Essentially what this does is allow you to select products by the letter/number they start with. Well, the starting letter of an item is rarely a useful criteria when I am shopping so I'm trying to create a more useful product sorter which will sort on date added, price and product name. and then filter based on attributes category.

**PROBLEM**

So I have managed to coerce the sorter to do my own query, which is working on everything except price.

Here is the SQL produced by my current set up for the price drop down:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.products_id, p.products_type, p.master_categories_id
               ,p.manufacturers_id, p.products_price, p.products_tax_class_id
               ,pd.products_description
               ,IF(s.status = 1, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL)
                  AS specials_new_products_price
               ,IF(s.status =1, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price)
                  AS final_price
               ,p.products_sort_order
               ,p.product_is_call
               ,p.product_is_always_free_shipping
               ,p.products_qty_box_status

  FROM products p
  LEFT JOIN specials s on p.products_id = s.products_id
  LEFT JOIN products_description pd on p.products_id = pd.products_id
  JOIN products_to_categories p2c on p.products_id = p2c.products_id

  WHERE p.products_status = 1
    and pd.language_id = '1'
    and p2c.categories_id = '1'

  GROUP BY p.products_id
  ORDER BY final_price ASC
```

As you can see I am trying to sort based on final price which is an alias for either the normal price or the special price (if set). This works fine through phpmyadmin. Unfortunately this isn't working through zen cart, I get the php error:

> PHP Fatal error:  1054:Unknown column 'final_price' in 'order clause'
>   :: SELECT p.products_id, p.products_price_sorter,
>   p.master_categories_id, p.manufacturers_id FROM products p LEFT JOIN
>   specials s on p.products_id = s.products_id LEFT JOIN
>   products_description pd on p.products_id = pd.products_id JOIN
>   products_to_categories p2c on p.products_id = p2c.products_id WHERE
>   p.products_status = 1\r\n       and pd.language_id = '1'\r\n       and
>   p2c.categories_id = '1' GROUP BY p.products_id ORDER BY final_price
>   ASC in /var/www/includes/classes/db/mysql/query_factory.php on line
>   101

So I looked at line 101 and it refers to an error handling method in the database abstraction class. Does anyone have any ideas what is going wrong here and how I might go about solving it?

Comment: Don't know about zen-cart. If it doesn't allow aliases, then you will be left with cutting and pasting the entire column def `ORDER BY IF(s.status =1, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price)`, or using a numeric column reference `ORDER BY 9`...

Comment: People who are looking at this in the future may also want to look at the contribution http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=1612 which has various sorting options.

Comment: @ScottWilson I hate you man. I just spent several days creating exactly what that plugin does (probably not as well either) and here you come swanning in with the solution after the hard slog. I searched for this and could not find it. But yes if you are reading this. Use that.

Comment: Ummm.... you couldn't find it because it was submitted and approved after you asked your question.  And you misspelled "thank you."

Comment: Thanks Scott, I was only joking I know it wasn't there before - I updated my answer with your link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all who looked at this. I managed to solve this. Not sure why but I noticed from my error message that the alias was not making it through to the db abstraction class. However, somewhere along the way it is producing p.products_price_sorter. So i managed to sort on price by using :

```
ORDER BY p.products_price_sorter
```

Hope this helps someone

**UPDATE**

After I spent several days getting this to work and play nicely, this plugin was suggested by Scott Wilson:
http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=1612
So if you are reading this it may be worth checking out - it allows for custom sorting of your products on advanced search and category pages.

Answer (score 1):

'final_price' is not actually a field in the database; it's part of each line item entry in the shopping cart object.  You could sort by base price (which would also be final price for products  which are not priced by attributes and don't have additional priced attributes) using the database.

Comment: That wouldnt take into account special prices though (discounts), where as p.products_price_sorter does - its an alternative if you don't want to include special prices in the sort. Luckily I only have one price attribute and its an optional extra. I wouldnt like to tackle this if I had attributes thrown into the mix.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does take into account built-in discounts such as sales, specials and quantity discounts (native to Zen Cart).

Comment: I saw from your site that you have a fair bit of experience in these matters. So maybe ignore my previous comment. But I cant actually see anything else price related being selected in the sql query throwing the error... I think that the sql query is coming from the dynamic filter plugin which may be (in fact definitely is) confusing matters. Either way I'm sorted now, I just need to get it to play nicely with dynamic filter.